# Adding picture to a CWEB document

Tags: graphics, web

The CWEB docs make no mention of how to include pictures. The tools I'm familiar with for including or generating graphics are designed for use in LaTeX, but CWEB outputs plain TeX. Pointers to examples of making this work would be appreciated, especially using EPS figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any cweb for a *long* time but... There is a `latex-cweb` package for using LaTeX with CWEB, or there is the `plain/miniltx` collection that allows you to use `\includegraphics` from plain, or you can perhaps process the plain TeX output in latex using the `plain` package.